# How can we receive notification for deleted non series-master recurring event using Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-calendar

I've subscribed to the user's calendar but when one/few of the recurring event(s) in the calendar is removed, then I just received notification for the series-master event along with all other events which are part of the recurrence.

Is there some way to determine the removed events?

Answer (score 1):

We don't get deleted notification when one/a few of the recurrent events get deleted. We need to fetch all occurrences of the event using recurrent master and then find the ones that got deleted if we had our previous entries stored in a persistent location.